# Beamer: set font size of beamercolorbox

Tags: beamer

I cannot figure out how to set the font size of a particular beamercolorbox in Beamer. I have a beamercolorbox called "box" which I invoke with the following command:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=4pt]{box}
```

I would like to set the font size of the text in this box. I tried putting the following in the preamble:

```
\setbeamerfont{box}{size={10}{12}}
```

But this does not produce any effect. What am I missing?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usecolortheme{beetle}

\setbeamercolor{box}{fg=black,bg=gray!50}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title of frame}

\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=4pt]{box}
“A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote.”
\end{beamercolorbox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I would like to reduce the font size of the beamercolorbox so that the long quotation fits more nicely on the page, not just for this particular box, but for all boxes of type "box".

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please provide MWE, that we can test a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fix font size with `{10}{12}`, you have to use `size*` option. And the command `\usebeamerfont` where you want it.

If you want to apply this size to all `box` boxes, you can declare a `newenvironment` like `mybox` in following code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usecolortheme{beetle}

\setbeamercolor{box}{fg=black,bg=gray!50}
\setbeamerfont{box}{size*={10}{12}}

\newenvironment<>{mybox}[1][]%
{\begin{beamercolorbox}[#1]{box}\usebeamerfont{box}}{\end{beamercolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title of frame}

\begin{mybox}[sep=4pt]
“A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote. A long quote.”
\end{mybox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thank you very much! A question about a detail: Why is there a little indent on the first line of the quote, and can this indent be eliminated?

Comment: @Wolfhart Add `%` after `[sep=4pt]`